# How to sort values by date and drop duplicates by a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame `df`:

```
import pandas as pd

mydictionary = {'id': ['11X', '11X', '22X', '33A'],
    'grade': [68, 74, 77, 78],
    'checkdate': ["2019-12-26", "2019-12-27", "2019-12-26", "2019-12-25"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(mydictionary)
```

I want to sort values by `checkdate` and drop duplicates by `id` while keeping the newest entries.

The expected result is this one:

```
id    grade   checkdate
11X   74      2019-12-27
22X   77      2019-12-26
33A   78      2019-12-25
```

I know how to sort values:

```
df.sort_values("checkdate")
```

Also, I know how to drop duplicates:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=["id"], keep='first', inplace=True)
```

But how to put these two things together?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you struggling to chain the two or are you asking whether there's a way to do it in a single step?

Comment: @roganjosh: I am more interested to do it in a single step. But even if I simply chain two, how can I keep the newest entries by date?

Comment: Exactly as you're doing, but either reversing the sort or using `keep='last'`. The only potential issue with what you've posted is that you've not used `inplace=True` in `sort_values`. Other than that, I think you've already worked it out

Comment: do you mean `df.sort_values("checkdate").drop_duplicates(subset=["id"], keep='first', inplace=True)`? or am I not understanding

Comment: @roganjosh: Do you mean that I should use `df.sort_values("checkdate", ascending=False, inplace=True)` and then drop duplicates with `keep='first'`?

Comment: @aws_apprentice: Isn't `ascending` True by default?

Comment: @Fluxy pretty much that. You can chain the two if you get rid of `inplace=True` for each individual operation and just assign back to a new name, but the principle is the same. `df = df.sort_values(by=['checkdate'], ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset=['id'], keep='first')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd

mydictionary = {'id': ['11X', '11X', '22X', '33A'],
                'grade': [68, 74, 77, 78],
                'checkdate': ["2019-12-26", "2019-12-27", "2019-12-26", "2019-12-25"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(mydictionary)

df['checkdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['checkdate'])
df2 = df.sort_values(by=['checkdate']).drop_duplicates('id', keep='last')
print(df2)
```

Result:

```
    id  grade  checkdate
3  33A     78 2019-12-25
2  22X     77 2019-12-26
1  11X     74 2019-12-27
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try other way by using `groupby`, `idxmax` and `slice`

```
df_out = df.loc[df.groupby('id').checkdate.idxmax()]

Out[1199]:
    id  grade  checkdate
1  11X     74 2019-12-27
2  22X     77 2019-12-26
3  33A     78 2019-12-25
```

*Note*: `df.checkdate` is in  `ISO8601` format/standard, so lexicographical order corresponds to chronological order

Comment: "Assume df.checkdate is already in correct datetime dtype" I don't think this matters because they're going along with ISO8601 so even the ordering of strings should be correct?

Comment: @roganjosh: hah, good point. It's in ISO8601 format, so lexicographical order corresponds to chronological order. I completely forgot about it :)